# How to add slack functionality with in my PHP app

Tags: php, slack-api, slack

I am looking to integrate slack functionality with in my PHP application. I would like to implement a user interface where user logs in to slack from my application and clicks on any of the existing team members from the list and chat with them(Login -> Send -> Receive messages) through direct messages. I have gone through slack web api documentation but have not found any article. Is this functionality possible through the web api? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to duplicate Slack’s functionality in your application. Why?

Comment: I have a requirement to implement a basic chat functionality to have a user chat with another team member through our application instead of logging into slack. This way users who are logged into our application can directly send and receive messages.